# While statement not stopping when it should

Tags: python, while-loop

this is my first post here. I'm new to Python and programming in general so I'm not sure where I went wrong. This is a solution I came up with to Problem #52 on Project Euler (I know it's probably not the best way either). My problem with this code is that the while statement doesn't break when it gets to the correct answer. It'll catch it and give me the answer only if I started num with the correct answer: 142857, but when I initialize it with anything else it continues counting right past 142857. The strange thing is I used the same exact method to answer another Euler Problem and that one works just fine. Can anyone please tell me why this is happening here? Thanks!

```
def digits(number):
    return [int(x) for x in str(number)]

def same_digits():
    num = 1
    x2 = sorted(digits(num*2))
    x3 = sorted(digits(num*3))
    x4 = sorted(digits(num*4))
    x5 = sorted(digits(num*5))
    x6 = sorted(digits(num*6))

    while x2 != x3 != x4 != x5 != x6:
        num += 1
    print num
```

Comment: Please don't remove the question - it may be useful to others! It also invalidates all answers below.

Comment: Yeah I realized that after I tried to delete it lol. Thanks for restoring it Sven =)

Sorry I'm new here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variables `x2` etc. are not changed inside the loop, so they will always keep their initial values.  If you want their values to be recalculated when `num` changes, you need to move that code into the loop.

Moreover, you are using comparison  operator chaining here.  The expression

```
x2 != x3 != x4 != x5 != x6
```

is equivalent to

```
x2 != x3 and x3 != x4 and x4 != x5 and x5 != x6
```

which probably isn't what you want.

Comment: The ands weren't the problem, but the first part was. Thanks

Comment: I'll remember that for the future then.

Answer (score 2):

The `while` loop will never break since `x2,x3,x4,x5,x6` are all at the same value. Only `num` changes in the loop.

In addition, `x2 != x3 != x4 != x5 != x6` looks fishy. To check if all numbers are distinct, try:

```
len(set([x2,x3,x4,x5,x6])) != 5
```

The `set` takes only the unique values and `len` counts the size of this "set". Even better put them in a list, say `R` and this becomes:

```
len(set(R)) != 5
```

Very handy when your list has more than `5` elements!

Comment: The OP actually needs `not x2 == x3 == x4 == x5 == x6`.

Comment: Yeah not putting my variables inside the while loop was the problem. The check I had does work as intended though. I'm not sure the method you described would do what I wanted it to. Thanks for answering.

Answer (score 1):

You're not modifying any of the `xi` arguments in the while loop, so the comparison never changes.